# Status update post

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm building a social media website and I'm getting this error with my code when users type in to add a new post it'll show up and stay is there a way to fix this issue? I've been dealing with this for several days and can't figure it out. My friend can't figure it out either what are we doing wrong.

```js
var main = function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    var post = $('.status-box').val();
    $('<li>').text(post).prependTo('.posts');
    $('.status-box').val('');
    $('.counter').text('140');
    $('.btn').addClass('disabled'); 
  });
  
  $('.status-box').keyup(function() {
    var postLength = $(this).val().length;
    var charactersLeft = 140 - postLength;
    $('.counter').text(charactersLeft);
  
    if(charactersLeft < 0) {
      $('.btn').addClass('disabled'); 
    }
    else if(charactersLeft == 140) {
      $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
    }
    else {
      $('.btn').removeClass('disabled');
    }
  });
  
  $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #404040;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.container {
  width: 520px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.button-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.counter {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.posts {
  clear: both;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.posts li {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  min-height: 42px;
}
```

```html
 
    <div class="container">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea class="form-control status-box" rows="2" placeholder="Blurt to friends?..."></textarea>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="button-group pull-right">
        <p class="counter">140</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Blurt</a>
      </div>
    
      <ul class="posts">
      </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: What exactly is the behavior you want?

Comment: when users write a new post I want them to post it just like Twitter has  how can i do that i have my status update but the javascript isn't working

Comment: Hmm. That seems to be working for me. I type in the box, hit 'blurt', and a box  appears below with my text. It I do it again, I get another box. Maybe a browser issue?

Comment: that's weird it gives errors in my text editor